# Rails: How to control CSS, Javascript files

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails

How can I control CSS and JavaScript files loading in Rails 4 instead of tree loading?

I am new with Rails and I noticed that it creates for me a new CSS, JS file for every controller but then includes them all on all pages thanks to  `*= require_tree .`.

I need two things please:

1. Have Rails automatically include the default CSS/JS file of my choice plus one CSS/JS by respective called controller
2. Be able to add a new special CSS/JS chosen in controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this.

1. Remove require_tree.
2. Change layout file, which includes CSS/JS matching the controller name.
3. Put CSS/JS in assets.
4. Make CSS/JS of controllers manifest.
5. Extend asset pipeline target files on production.rb.

Example for aaas controller

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
```

application.css

```
/*
 *= require_self
 *= require font-awesome
 *= require_tree ./pepper-grinder
 *= require ./ui.jqgrid
 */
```

layouts/application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Log Analyzer</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag     controller.controller_name , media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag controller.controller_name , "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
```

app/assets/javascripts/aaas.js

```
//= require jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min
//= require grid.locale-ja
//= require aaas_main
```

app/assets/stylesheets/aaas.css

```
/*
 *= require_self
 *= require aaas_main
 */
```

config/environments/production.rb

```
  #config.serve_static_assets = false

  config.assets.precompile += %w( aaas.js )
  config.assets.precompile += %w( aaas.css )
```

run

```
$ rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
$ rails s -e production
```